# Issue with Dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql

Having some issues with my query in that it generates the required data between the dates specified (on live it is 2 date fields (date_from and date_to), but the order of data is in the wrong order. e.g it will appear

```
JAN 2017 | MARCH 2017 | APRIL 2017 | FEB 2017
```

And the most baffling issue is that it generates data outside what you search. e.g if you search from 1-1-2017 to date, it adds December to the data but there is no data in the database containing december records.

The code used to generate the dynamic pivot chart is:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(".$period." FROM redeem_pledge) = ',
          EXTRACT(".$period." FROM redeem_pledge),
          ' THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `',
          EXTRACT(".$period." FROM redeem_pledge),
          '`'
        )
      ) AS `pivot_columns`
    FROM record_pledge
    WHERE redeem_pledge BETWEEN ? AND ?
    ORDER BY redeem_pledge asc
";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$date_from = $this->input->get('date_from') ? $this->input->get('date_from') : '2017-05-01';
$date_to   = $this->input->get('date_to') ? $this->input->get('date_to') : date('Y-m-d');
$stmt->execute([$date_from, $date_to]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->closeCursor();
$pivot_columns = $row['pivot_columns'];

$sql = "
    SELECT title AS `Pledge Purpose`, {$pivot_columns}
    FROM record_pledge t1
    JOIN setting_pledge_purpose ON t1.purpose_pledge = setting_pledge_purpose.id
    WHERE t1.redeem_pledge BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY title asc WITH ROLLUP
";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$date_from, $date_to]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Image of Added data and unorganised data:

[image]

UPDATE echo of SQL- SEARCH FROM 01-01-2017(JAN) - 15-10-2017(OCT) :

```
SELECT title AS `Pledge Purpose`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201701 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201701`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201702 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201702`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201704 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201704`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201705 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201705`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201706 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201706`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201708 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201708`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM redeem_pledge) = 201709 THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `201709` 
FROM record_pledge t1 JOIN setting_pledge_purpose ON t1.purpose_pledge = setting_pledge_purpose.id 
WHERE t1.redeem_pledge BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY title asc WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` option to the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Comment: There is one there

Comment: No there isn't. You have it in the `SELECT`, not in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. `GROUP_CONCAT(expression ORDER BY column)`

Comment: thanks i've seen the mistake and the data is ordering correct but i'm still getting data that is not suppose to be there on the end

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `ORDER BY` option in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, not the `SELECT` query.

Also, you need to put quotes around the value returned by `EXTRACT($period FROM redeem_pledge)`. If `$period` is a unit that returns multiple parts of the date, like `YEAR_MONTH`, it needs to be compared as a string because it will be `2017-01`; if you don't quote it, it will be treated as a numeric subtraction.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(".$period." FROM redeem_pledge) = \"',
          EXTRACT(".$period." FROM redeem_pledge),
          '\" THEN AMOUNT else 0 END) AS `',
          EXTRACT(".$period." FROM redeem_pledge),
          '`'
        )
      ORDER BY redeem_pledge ASC) AS `pivot_columns`
    FROM record_pledge
    WHERE redeem_pledge BETWEEN ? AND ?

";
```

Comment: The data is ordering correctly but I am still getting data at the end that is not suppose to be there

Comment: Maybe there's a timezone issue, so something from the last few hours of December 31 is being treated as January 1.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but I don't think that is it. the december data that shows up is from 2017 not  2016.. so if it was adding data from december 31, it would be from december 31st 2016. The data it adds on is completely made up when I look in the database because there is no record after october, so the data for november and december come from nowhere!!

Comment: Can you show what `echo $sql;` shows after you combine `$pivot_columns` into the SQL?

Comment: What's the value of `$period`?

Comment: I think maybe the problem is that you didn't put quotes around the `EXTRACT` value. See my updated answer.

Comment: Using your updated answer I get a syntax error, i've updated my question to invlude $sql and also $period changes the type of EXTRACT that the query uses. So it changes from YEAR_MONTH, YEARWEEK, YEAR, QUATER(although this isn't full functional )

Comment: I found something interesting, the extra dates are only generated if I search past the 12th of each month on the date_to. Don't know what that the issue with that is but aside from that your first answer fixed my issue. if you have any answer to my recent discovery please let me know, otherwise i'll mark as correct answer.

Comment: I needed to escape the quotes I added, I've fixed that.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in sqlfiddle?

Comment: sadly I can't, I can only do it when I am using the live version of my code.

Comment: Where is the December data showing up? The query only has columns from `201701` to `201709`. And why isn't there any `201710` column?

Comment: Exactly my point.. I really don't understand it. But I have found something out. on my date_to if I search below the 12th of October, it doesn't add the extra months at the end. Strange.

Comment: Can you post sample data and the result you're getting? I'm having a hard time picturing the problem, let alone the solution.

Comment: And when you use that data with `$date_to == '2017-10-13` you get a `201712` column? Can you show the incorrect output you're getting?

Comment: if you look at the image It has November and December although I searched from 2017-01-01 to 2017-10-15 (15th october), You can also see that July is included in the image but if you look at the query July doesn't exist.

Comment: The query only has `201701` through `201709` in the `SELECT` list. It's simply impossible for it to return columns that aren't in that list. So either the query isn't as you've shown, or there's a problem with the code that creates the HTML table from `$result`.